# How can I make an inline trees many2many field look okay in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I have a tree view with a many2many field `require_weekday`:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view"
       id="sale_order_email_collection_form">
 <field name="name">sale.order_email.collection.form</field>
 <field name="model">sale.order_email.collection</field>
 <field name="arch" type="xml">
   <form string="Collection">
     <group>
       <field name="name"/>
     </group>
     <field name="emails">
       <tree string="Lines" editable="bottom">
         <field name="required_weekday"/>
       </tree>
     </field>
   </form>
 </field>
</record>
```

When I click the many2many field it's basically unusable with some blue text overlaying the tree view making it impossible to tell what's going on.

[image]

Is it possible to make it work decent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use widget="many2many_tags" in xml.
for example :

```
<field name="fields_name" widget="many2many_tags"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `widget="one2many"` in xml.

This will change `many2many` form view to `one2many` as you want.

For Example:

```
<field name="your_many2many_field" widget="one2many">
    <tree string="your string" editable="top/bottom">
        <field name="your_fields"/>#Define all your fields for tree view
    </tree>
</field?
```